# How to quickly flatten nested list of dictionaries with more nested list of dicts inside of df column?

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-lists

Sample of my data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "sport_key": "americanfootball_nfl",
        "sport_title": "NFL",
        "commence_time": "2022-10-28T00:15:00Z",
        "home_team": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
        "away_team": "Baltimore Ravens",
        "bookmakers": [
            {
                "key": "betonlineag",
                "title": "BetOnline.ag",
                "last_update": "2022-10-26T00:34:17Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Baltimore Ravens",
                                "price": 1.8
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
                                "price": 2.04
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "fanduel",
                "title": "FanDuel",
                "last_update": "2022-10-26T00:34:30Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Baltimore Ravens",
                                "price": 1.85
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
                                "price": 2.0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "sport_key": "americanfootball_nfl",
        "sport_title": "NFL",
        "commence_time": "2022-10-30T13:30:00Z",
        "home_team": "Jacksonville Jaguars",
        "away_team": "Denver Broncos",
        "bookmakers": [
            {
                "key": "betonlineag",
                "title": "BetOnline.ag",
                "last_update": "2022-10-26T00:34:17Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Denver Broncos",
                                "price": 2.2
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Jacksonville Jaguars",
                                "price": 1.71
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "betrivers",
                "title": "BetRivers",
                "last_update": "2022-10-26T00:34:31Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Denver Broncos",
                                "price": 2.26
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Jacksonville Jaguars",
                                "price": 1.7
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like for my data to look like this:

| id | sport_title | home_team | away_team | bookmaker_name | market_type | home_team_odds | away_team_odds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | NFL | Tampa Bay Buccaneers | Baltimore Ravens | belonlineag | h2h | 2.04 | 1.8 |
| 0001 | NFL | Tampa Bay Buccaneers | Baltimore Ravens | fanduel | h2h | 2.0 | 1.85 |
| 0002 | NFL | Jacksonville Jaguars | Denver Broncos | betonlineag | h2h | 1.71 | 2.2 |
| 0002 | NFL | Jacksonville Jaguars | Denver Broncos | betrivers | h2h | 1.7 | 2.26 |

What's tripping me up is that I don't know how to efficiently unpack the list of dictionaries and keep the data I want in a row.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different way.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    record_path=["bookmakers", "markets", "outcomes"],
    meta=["id", "sport_title", "home_team", "away_team", ["markets", "key"], ["markets", "outcomes", "key"]],
).rename(columns={"markets.key": "bookmaker_name", "markets.outcomes.key": "market_type"})

df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]

df = df.assign(
    home_team_odds=np.where(df["home_team"].eq(df["name"]), df["price"], ""),
    away_team_odds=np.where(df["away_team"].eq(df["name"]), df["price"], "")
).drop(columns=["name", "price"])

df = df.groupby(
    ["id", "sport_title", "home_team", "away_team", "bookmaker_name", "market_type"]
).agg({"home_team_odds": "last", "away_team_odds": "first"}).reset_index()

print(df)

     id sport_title             home_team         away_team bookmaker_name market_type home_team_odds away_team_odds
0  0001         NFL  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  Baltimore Ravens    betonlineag         h2h           2.04            1.8
1  0001         NFL  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  Baltimore Ravens        fanduel         h2h            2.0           1.85
2  0002         NFL  Jacksonville Jaguars    Denver Broncos    betonlineag         h2h           1.71            2.2
3  0002         NFL  Jacksonville Jaguars    Denver Broncos      betrivers         h2h            1.7           2.26
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution as well! Just when you posted it I found that the odds weren't always lining up with the correct team with the other solution. Grouping it the way you do seems to solve that

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same issue here too. `df.loc[df['home_team_odds'] == '']` returns quite a few rows. some of these aren't updating, even when there are odds. I wonder if there's some kind of misalignment in the dict that's causing that

Comment: Sorry do you mean on full data its mis-aligning?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That's what I meant. I checked the data after the json_normalization and before the column assignment to make sure, and there is no missing data. Still investigating where it disappears to.

Comment: Aaaand found the issue. somewhere along the line the odds flip from {"home_team_odds": "last", "away_team_odds": "first"} to {"home_team_odds": "first", "away_team_odds": "last"}.

using 'max' for both seems to work well when there are only 2 outcomes

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `pd.json_normalize`

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['bookmakers', 'markets'],
                       meta=['id', 'sport_title', 'home_team', 'away_team', ['bookmakers', 'key']])
df = (df.assign(home_team_odds=df['outcomes'].str[1].str['price'],
                away_team_odds=df['outcomes'].str[0].str['price'])
      .rename(columns={'bookmakers.key': 'bookmaker_name', 'key': 'market_type'})
      .drop(columns='outcomes'))
```

```
print(df)

  market_type    id sport_title             home_team         away_team bookmaker_name  home_team_odds  away_team_odds
0         h2h  0001         NFL  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  Baltimore Ravens    betonlineag            2.04            1.80
1         h2h  0001         NFL  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  Baltimore Ravens        fanduel            2.00            1.85
2         h2h  0002         NFL  Jacksonville Jaguars    Denver Broncos    betonlineag            1.71            2.20
3         h2h  0002         NFL  Jacksonville Jaguars    Denver Broncos      betrivers            1.70            2.26
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I started playing with json_normalize thanks to the comment, but your solution is so elegant. Love it!